# Unidirectional relationship in databases

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relation

Reading a book about UML, it mentiond that DB does not support unidirectional relationships. Is that correct? I thought there were ways how to achieve that but my knowledge of DBs is very limited.

Comment: I just wonder if that could be a book by Scott Ambler by any chance? Anyway, it is wrong. In fact so mistaken it is not even wrong.